# Change all file icons with same type [Yosemite]

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, finder

I have many excel files in my computer, and the icon of all of them are plain paper, like this:
[image]

I want all icons to be .numbers icon. Do anyone know how to do that ?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 8):

Here's what you could do :

- Open a Finder window and navigate to /Applications/
- Find the app whose file icon you want to change
- Right click it and select "Show Package Contents"
- Navigate to Contents/Resources/ and find the appropriate icon file. Replace it with your new icon file.
- Restart your computer to update the icon cache.

Or you can change the default app for a file type and set all files of that type to be associated with the default app if that's what your question says:

- Open a Finder window and locate the file type you want to change.
- Push Command+i or go to File > Get Info
- Under "Open With" select the app you like. You have just changed the default app for that individual file.
- To change the default for all files of that type, push the "Change All" button and then "Continue"

This will make all your excel files to open with numbers while the previous one will just change the icon

Comment: I'm talking about changing the icon of any file type, even if it is unknown type. In addition, I do not have Microsoft Excel installed in my computer. All excel files are originally made in another windows computer and shared  with my computer.

Comment: I have changed the "Open With" app to be "Numbers". the icon do not change.

Comment: Restart your mac. Should change the icon then

Comment: I have just restarted my mac. nothing changed.

Comment: 1) Is it necessary to restart the computer or is restarting Finder enough?

2) Does this work on MacOS?  I've tried it and it doesn't work for me.  It used to, but not with the OS upgrade.

Comment: change the default program to open and then relaunch Finder, worked for me

Answer (score 3):

To change the file icon on all you files icons with the same extension:

- open Get Info panel file 1, that you want to change
- open Get Info panel file 2, that you want to change to
- drag and drop icon from panel file 1 to panel file 2
- click Change All...
- with Finder open "Show View Options" or command + J
- drag Icon size as you wish. This force icons cache rebuild

Comment: This answer correctly addresses the "change all" aspect of the question, without also changing the app that's used to open the files. +1

Comment: I followed these instructions on Mojave, and after I resize the icon in Show View Options in the last step, all other files with the same extension have old icon still. Is restart required?

Comment: Nope @ChrisHeady, here It worked without a restart :(

Comment: Did not work on Monterey.

Comment: Yeah, sorry @kenj , the question is about Yosemite. I did not even try on Monterey :(

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution that works all times:

1. Find the file with icon that you want to apply for (ex: *.numbers file), then Command + i to open it's info Panel
2. Find the file you want to apply the icon for (ex: your *.xlsx) file. then Command + i to open it's info Panel
3. Now that you have your two file's info panel side by side, you can drag the icon from the first file's panel ( only from header/title bar ) and apply it to a second file's panel, as shown:[image: you must place the icon over the second icon to make it work] (you must place the icon over the second icon to make it work, I didn't make it overlap just for taking a clear screenshot)
4. Open a champagne and celebrate!

Comment: It does not completely solve the problem because I have to do it for each file, but it really helps. Thanks!

Comment: It will change for only one file, don't will change for all files of that type.

Answer (score -1):

You have to empty your cache for icons after you have changed the icon or switched the file association program. 
Not sure the exact filename, but use it to empty both cache folders. `~/Library/Caches` and `/Users/User/Library/Caches`